# Functional patterns for better chaining of collect

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I often find myself needing to chain `collects` where I want to do multiple collects in a single traversal. I also would like to return a "remainder" for things that don't match any of the collects.

For example:

```scala
sealed trait Animal
case class Cat(name: String) extends Animal
case class Dog(name: String, age: Int) extends Animal

val animals: List[Animal] =
  List(Cat("Bob"), Dog("Spot", 3), Cat("Sally"), Dog("Jim", 11))

// Normal way
val cats: List[Cat]    = animals.collect { case c: Cat => c }
val dogAges: List[Int] = animals.collect { case Dog(_, age) => age }
val rem: List[Animal]  = Nil // No easy way to create this without repeated code
```

This really isn't great, it requires multiple iterations and there is no reasonable way to calculate the remainder. I *could* write a very complicated fold to pull this off, but it would be really nasty.

Instead, I usually opt for mutation which is fairly similar to the logic you would have in a `fold`:

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

// Ugly, hide the mutation away
val (cats2, dogsAges2, rem2) = {
  // Lose some benefits of type inference
  val cs = ListBuffer[Cat]()
  val da = ListBuffer[Int]()
  val rem = ListBuffer[Animal]()
  // Bad separation of concerns, I have to merge all of my functions
  animals.foreach {
    case c: Cat      => cs += c
    case Dog(_, age) => da += age
    case other       => rem += other
  }
  (cs.toList, da.toList, rem.toList)
}
```

I don't like this one bit, it has worse type inference and separation of concerns since I have to merge all of the various partial functions. It also requires lots of lines of code.

What I want, are some useful patterns, like a `collect` that returns the remainder (I grant that [`partitionMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/collection/IterableOps.html#partitionMap%5BA1,A2%5D(f:A=%3EEither%5BA1,A2%5D):(CC%5BA1%5D,CC%5BA2%5D)) new in 2.13 does this, but uglier). I also could use some form of `pipe` or `map` for operating on parts of tuples. Here are some made up utilities:

```scala
implicit class ListSyntax[A](xs: List[A]) {
  import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
  // Collect and return remainder
  // A specialized form of new 2.13 partitionMap
  def collectR[B](pf: PartialFunction[A, B]): (List[B], List[A]) = {
    val rem = new ListBuffer[A]()
    val res = new ListBuffer[B]()
    val f = pf.lift
    for (elt <- xs) {
      f(elt) match {
        case Some(r) => res += r
        case None    => rem += elt
      }
    }
    (res.toList, rem.toList)
  }
}
implicit class Tuple2Syntax[A, B](x: Tuple2[A, B]){
  def chainR[C](f: B => C): Tuple2[A, C] = x.copy(_2 = f(x._2))
}
```

Now, I can write this in a way that *could* be done in a single traversal (with a lazy datastructure) and yet follows functional, immutable practice:

```scala
// Relatively pretty, can imagine lazy forms using a single iteration
val (cats3, (dogAges3, rem3)) =
  animals.collectR          { case c: Cat => c }
         .chainR(_.collectR { case Dog(_, age) => age })
```

My question is, are there patterns like this? It smells like the type of thing that would be in a library like Cats, FS2, or ZIO, but I am not sure what it might be called.

Scastie link of code examples: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Egz78fnGR6KyqlUTNTv9DQ

Comment: Why not just `groupBy`?

Comment: `groupBy` requires some key type parameter, what is common about collecting `Cats`, collecting `Dog` names, and leaving the rest alone? It also still requires merging all of the partial functions although I could live with it.

Comment: I'm perplexed when mention _"Bad separation of concerns, I have to merge all of my functions"_ because you want a result like `(Seq[Cat], Seq[Int], Seq[Animal])` as opposed to `Seq[Any]` or some kind of `HList`. The fixed arity and heterogenous nature of the results suggest, to my admittedly naïve mind, that the concerns belong together. Actually, thinking it over, I suppose you are trying to construct an arbitrary `HList` with `chainR`

Comment: `chainR` is certainly constructing a bad implementation of an `HList`. I admit I'm not familiar with using `HLists`, but this seems kind of like `unfolding` an `HList` with a `partitionMap` at each step. If the input `Iterable` were lazy then perhaps all of the results could be constructed in a single traversal while maintaining the types I'm looking for.

Comment: You can do something like this: `data.groupBy(x => predicates.indexWhere(p => p(x)))`

Comment: I can see `groupBy` or `groupByMap` working with some abstraction across my partial functions, but then you end up with `List[Any]` which isn't great either, I also suspect it'll be as ugly as the mutation.

Comment: You could make the predicate return some ADT so you can overcome the `Any` - Anyways, this doesn't seem at all like a common requirement so it is not surprising that the solution is more complex and boilerplate than expected. I would question if you really need to ensure just one traversal, in any case if raw cpu performance is that important a simple whole loop over plain arrays would be the best.

Comment: I would suggest using Shapeless's HLists to have this chained collect operation work for an arbitrary number of categories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about defining a couple utility classes to help you with this?

```
case class ListCollect[A](list: List[A]) {
  def partialCollect[B](f: PartialFunction[A, B]): ChainCollect[List[B], A] = {
    val (cs, rem) = list.partition(f.isDefinedAt)
    new ChainCollect((cs.map(f), rem))
  }
}

case class ChainCollect[A, B](tuple: (A, List[B])) {
  def partialCollect[C](f: PartialFunction[B, C]): ChainCollect[(A, List[C]), B] = {
    val (cs, rem) = tuple._2.partition(f.isDefinedAt)
    ChainCollect(((tuple._1, cs.map(f)), rem))
  }
}
```

`ListCollect` is just meant to start the chain, and `ChainCollect` takes the previous remainder (the second element of the tuple) and tries to apply a `PartialFunction` to it, creating a new `ChainCollect` object. I'm not particularly fond of the nested tuples this produces, but you may be able to make it look a bit better if you use Shapeless's `HList`s.

```
val ((cats, dogs), rem) = ListCollect(animals)
  .partialCollect { case c: Cat => c }
  .partialCollect { case Dog(_, age) => age }
  .tuple
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/vrFNoPV6TYOieqdVtZx2ig)

---

Dotty's `*:` type makes this a bit easier:

```
opaque type ChainResult[Prev <: Tuple, Rem] = (Prev, List[Rem])

extension [P <: Tuple, R, N](chainRes: ChainResult[P, R]) {
  def partialCollect(f: PartialFunction[R, N]): ChainResult[List[N] *: P, R] = {
    val (cs, rem) = chainRes._2.partition(f.isDefinedAt)
    (cs.map(f) *: chainRes._1, rem)
  }
}
```

This does end up in the output being reversed, but it doesn't have that ugly nesting from my previous approach:

```
val ((owls, dogs, cats), rem) = (EmptyTuple, animals)
  .partialCollect { case c: Cat => c }
  .partialCollect { case Dog(_, age) => age }
  .partialCollect { case Owl(wisdom) => wisdom }

/* more animals */

case class Owl(wisdom: Double) extends Animal
case class Fly(isAnimal: Boolean) extends Animal

val animals: List[Animal] =
  List(Cat("Bob"), Dog("Spot", 3), Cat("Sally"), Dog("Jim", 11), Owl(200), Fly(false))
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JbBU70fVQbm2YVgmZ2Xquw)

And if you still don't like that, you can always define a few more helper methods to reverse the tuple, add the extension on a List without requiring an EmptyTuple to begin with, etc.

```
//Add this to the ChainResult extension
def end: Reverse[List[R] *: P] = {
    def revHelp[A <: Tuple, R <: Tuple](acc: A, rest: R): RevHelp[A, R] =
      rest match {
        case EmptyTuple => acc.asInstanceOf[RevHelp[A, R]]
        case h *: t => revHelp(h *: acc, t).asInstanceOf[RevHelp[A, R]]
      }
    revHelp(EmptyTuple, chainRes._2 *: chainRes._1)
  }

//Helpful types for safety
type Reverse[T <: Tuple] = RevHelp[EmptyTuple, T]
type RevHelp[A <: Tuple, R <: Tuple] <: Tuple = R match {
  case EmptyTuple => A
  case h *: t => RevHelp[h *: A, t]
}
```

And now you can do this:

```
val (cats, dogs, owls, rem) = (EmptyTuple, animals)
  .partialCollect { case c: Cat => c }
  .partialCollect { case Dog(_, age) => age }
  .partialCollect { case Owl(wisdom) => wisdom }
  .end
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/rlS2BXEqQziEAbDWhwUgqg)

Comment: I think utility classes are the way to go. I haven't used Dotty much so I really appreciate the Dotty example as well, it does look pretty nice :)

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to see just how "nasty" a `fold()` would be.

```
val (cats
    ,dogAges
    ,rem) = animals.foldRight((List.empty[Cat]
                              ,List.empty[Int]
                              ,List.empty[Animal])) {
  case (c:Cat,   (cs,ds,rs)) => (c::cs, ds, rs)
  case (Dog(_,d),(cs,ds,rs)) => (cs, d::ds, rs)
  case (r,       (cs,ds,rs)) => (cs, ds, r::rs)
}
```

Eye of the beholder I suppose.

Comment: Thank you for providing the extra example! My main issue is that it's n^2 in text for `n` categories. For 3 it's tolerable, but what about 5? 10? As with most questions this is a simple example to illustrate a point, `n` is often larger than 3 (but less than 10).

Comment: As far as I know foldRight does single traversal.

Comment: Sorry, I think my abuse of Big-O terminology is unclear. I mean the amount of text you have to write scales quadratically. If you were to add a 4th category (say `List[Owl]`), there are two 3x3 matrices of text in those cases that have to be expanded to 4x4. The performance is fine, the code is really painful to modify or extend.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned cats, I would also add solution using `foldMap`:

```
sealed trait Animal
case class Cat(name: String) extends Animal
case class Dog(name: String) extends Animal
case class Snake(name: String) extends Animal

val animals: List[Animal] = List(Cat("Bob"), Dog("Spot"), Cat("Sally"), Dog("Jim"), Snake("Billy"))

val map = animals.foldMap{ //Map(other -> List(Snake(Billy)), cats -> List(Cat(Bob), Cat(Sally)), dogs -> List(Dog(Spot), Dog(Jim)))
  case d: Dog => Map("dogs" -> List(d))
  case c: Cat => Map("cats" -> List(c))
  case o => Map("other" -> List(o))
}

val tuples = animals.foldMap{ //(List(Dog(Spot), Dog(Jim)),List(Cat(Bob), Cat(Sally)),List(Snake(Billy)))
  case d: Dog => (List(d), Nil, Nil)
  case c: Cat => (Nil, List(c), Nil)
  case o => (Nil, Nil, List(o))
}
```

Arguably it's more succinct than fold version, but it has to combine partial results using monoids, so it won't be as performant.

Comment: Solid suggestion, I think it's better than a vanilla fold. Thanks for the example!

Answer (score 2):

This code is dividing a list into three sets, so the natural way to do this is to use `partition` twice:

```
val (cats, notCat) = animals.partitionMap{
  case c: Cat => Left(c)
  case x => Right(x)
}

val (dogAges, rem) = notCat.partitionMap {
  case Dog(_, age) => Left(age)
  case x => Right(x)
}
```

A helper method can simplify this

```
def partitionCollect[T, U](list: List[T])(pf: PartialFunction[T, U]): (List[U], List[T]) =
  list.partitionMap {
    case t if pf.isDefinedAt(t) => Left(pf(t))
    case x => Right(x)
  }

val (cats, notCat) = partitionCollect(animals) { case c: Cat => c }
val (dogAges, rem) = partitionCollect(notCat) { case Dog(_, age) => age }
```

This is clearly extensible to more categories, with the slight irritation of having to invent temporary variable names (which could be overcome by explicit n-way partition methods)

Comment: Yeah I think `partitionMap` is the best option directly from the standardlib, and just wrapping it with a little sugar to make `PartialFunctions` work is about as good as it's going to get. Thanks!